# Internal build system error on opening Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build-error

So basically what happend is I've pulled changes from git repository (Fork to be percise) and now all of my Unity projects are opening with either of two errors:

```
Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2
[  0/950    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1900b0aEDbg.dag/UnityEditor.UI.rsp
[  0/950    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1900b0aEDbg.dag/Unity.Burst.AdditionalFile.txt
...
```

or

```
internal build system error. backend exited with code -1073741819
```

My console also returns a bunch of wuestion marks from time to time:
[image]

I've tried almost everything and nothing helped:

- Delete Bee folder
- Open with another Unity editor version
- Reinstall Unity Editor then reinstalled Unity Hub
- Restarted my PC
- Tried different compatibility levels in Project Setting

Plus none of the threads I've read gave the direct solution. I'm now in full panick mode, this error has been sitting there for two days now. Does anyone have any ideas what else could I do to fix this?

Comment: Delete the entire library folder, it should not have been inside source control in the first place, unity automatically creates this locally from the other files in the project.

Comment: Also tried that, didn't help. And if I remember correctly library folder wasn't inside source control either.